# How to filter words in db.body

Tags: web2py, web2py-modules

I am working on a program that I want to filter out some words, with nltk style of removing the stopwords as follows:

```
def phrasefilter(phrase):
    phrase = phrase.replace('hi', 'hello')
    phrase = phrase.replace('hey', 'hello')
    phrase = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9\s]+', '', phrase.lower())
    noise_words_set = ['of', 'the', 'at', 'for', 'in', 'and', 'is', 'from', 'are', 'our', 'it', 'its', 'was', 'when', 'how', 'what', 'like', 'whats', 'now', 'panic', 'very']
    return ' '.join(w for w in phrase.split() if w.lower() not in noise_words_set)
```

Is there a way of doing this on web2py DAL.

```
db.define_table( words,
    Field(words1, REQUIRES  IS_NOT_NULL(), REQUIRES....
```

I want to put it in the REQUIRES IS_NOT_IN_NOISE_WORDS_SET() constraints for example. Is this possible? Am working on a user input( with strings saved to the db) where it automatically deletes the stopwords I have chosen instead of the using the snippet shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options. First, you can create a custom validator that simply acts as a filter. A validator takes a value and returns a tuple including the (possibly transformed) value and either `None` or an error message (in this case, we want to return `None` as the second element of the tuple given that we are only transforming the value but not checking for errors).

```
def filter_noise_words(input):
    filtered_input = [code to remove stop words]
    return (filtered_input, None)

db.define_table('words',
                Field('words1', requires=[filter_noise_words, IS_NOT_EMPTY()]))
```

Note, the `IS_NOT_EMPTY` validator comes after the filtering to ensure the post-filtered input is not empty.

Another option would be to do the filtering via the [filter_in](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#filter_in-and-filter_out) attribute of the field:

```
def filter_noise_words(input):
    filtered_input = [code to remove stop words]
    return filtered_input

db.define_table('words',
                Field('words1', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(), filter_in=filter_noise_words))
```

The advantage of using `filter_in` is that it applies to all inserts and updates (made via the DAL), whereas a validator would only be applied when using SQLFORM (or when explicitly calling the special `.validate_and_insert` and `.validate_and_update` methods). The disadvantage of `filter_in` is that the filter is applied *after* any validators, so `IS_NOT_EMPTY` would run on the pre-filtered input.

Finally, rather than filtering the input before storing it, you might consider storing the original input and then either storing the filtered input in a separate [computed field](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Computed-fields) or using a [virtual field](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Virtual-fields).